# Help identify vintage kids bike

Tags: vintage, cruiser, children

I found this bike under our house we recently purchased. Wasn't able to find anything online and was wondering if anyone knows this type of bike? and if its worth fixing up for my son.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing "Holland" make in the UK.   Are you in the UK ?

Comment: That looks kind-of Franken-bikey, to me. I'm not convinced the seat is original to the bike, especially given the adjustable fitting at the rear axle.

Comment: @Criggie located in Australia so was a little confused by the Holland logo

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah good point, does look a little like an afterthought the banana seat

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this "Holland" brand before, but not recently.  And, of course, since there are a few bikes in Holland the country Google is not much help.  But I suspect it's a department store bike of the 50s or 60s (note the cottered crank), and the banana seat was an after-market addition.  As to fixing it up, finding parts would be a challenge -- likely the bearings are rusted out.

Comment: could be fun to do as a project, but its not going to be a good bike due to the fork bend noted by others.  I'd suggest you flogg it off on gumtree or similar as a "as-found barn find resto" candidate.  Also, it looks quite small so there's a good chance your son will be too big for it by the time all the fixup work is done.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider it scrap metal. There are a few safety concerns. While millions of us survived childhood on bikes like these they don't meet current safety standards. The single coaster brake means that if the chain broke or fell off there would be no brakes. Modern bikes have hand brake mounted along with the coaster brake. The lack of a chain guard is a danger as a pant leg could get caught. The fork also appears to be bent as if the bike was in some sort of frontal crash. If your goal is an inexpensive bike consider used as children quickly outgrow them and most have limited use.

Comment: This is good advice. There are plenty of good used kids bike available for what you'd pay to replace just the rotted tires on this bike.

Answer (score 2):

Fork looks bent pushed back. There are no brakes and seems to be no provision for fitting any (rims don't even seem to have a brake pad track). Definitely recommend against fixing it up for a child.

Comment: Uh, it almost certainly has a coaster brake.